# how can I write file names and parent folder name where ?s are

Tags: vbscript

- How can I replace the ? with the parent folder name, not path

```html
<Name>VEH_"?"</Name>
```

- create list from file names and add a prefix and suffix
- the file name must go where the "?" is

```html
<Item><Name>?</Name><Variations type="NULL"/></Item>
```

- I dont know how to achieve the first or third step correctly

The code:

```html
Dim fso, folder, files, OutputFile
Dim strPath

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
 
' Create a FileSystemObject  
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Define folder we want to list files from
strPath = "D:\folder\img"
 
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(strPath)
Set files = folder.Files
 
' Create text file to output test data
Set OutputFile = fso.CreateTextFile("Vehichlespawnwhead.txt", True)
OutputFile.WriteLine("<Name>VEH_"parentfoldername"</Name>")
  OutputFile.WriteLine("")

' Loop through each file  
For each item In files
 
  ' Output file properties to a text file
  OutputFile.WriteLine("<Item><Name>(item.Name)</Name><Variations type=""NULL""/></Item>")
  OutputFile.WriteLine("")
   
Next
 
' Close text file
OutputFile.Close
```

right now if ran the text file would read

```html
<Name>VEH_"parentfoldername"</Name>

<Item><Name>(item.Name)</Name><Variations type="NULL"/></Item>
<Item><Name>(item.Name)</Name><Variations type="NULL"/></Item>
```

- my goal is

```html
<Name>VEH_img</Name>
  <Item><Name>file1</Name><Variations type="NULL"/></Item>
  <Item><Name>file2</Name><Variations type="NULL"/></Item>
```

the file1 and file2 shouldnt include their extensions

sorry for format issues im brand new

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.  You are very close!

All you need to do is use `folder.Name` (line 18), and use `fso.GetBaseName(item.Name)` in your For loop (line 25); and of course, use proper string concatenation too.

For example:

```
Dim fso, folder, files, OutputFile
Dim strPath

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
 
' Create a FileSystemObject  
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Define folder we want to list files from
strPath = "D:\folder\img"
 
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(strPath)
Set files = folder.Files
 
' Create text file to output test data
Set OutputFile = fso.CreateTextFile("Vehichlespawnwhead.txt", True)
OutputFile.WriteLine("<Name>VEH_" & folder.Name & "</Name>")
  OutputFile.WriteLine("")

' Loop through each file  
For each item In files
 
  ' Output file properties to a text file
  OutputFile.WriteLine("<Item><Name>" & fso.GetBaseName(item.Name) & "</Name><Variations type=""NULL""/></Item>")
  OutputFile.WriteLine("")
   
Next
 
' Close text file
OutputFile.Close
```

Enjoy.